# Get Java file path in the format with "\\"

Tags: java

I have a Java code which uses the `JFileChooser` component and it gets the folder path in the format `D:\Folder\subfolder`.

When I use this path to create a new file it does not accept.

So, is there a way I can convert this path to `D:\\release\\subfolder` or is there any other way to proceed?

Comment: Just replace \ with /.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the backslashes?

Comment: @Harsha You should find first is there some kind of questions already on StackOverflow or not ? okk  tthen only put your owns. It may harm your reputation is duplicate questions found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String replacement can be the answer.

```
public class FilePathChanger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "D:\\Folder\\subfolder";
        filePath = filePath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(filePath);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Tom : I have updated code.